# How to translate some image in background, with infinite repeat count, and image change

Tags: android, animation, layout

I want to translate image on background with a foreground blur. I got image from external database (not implemented yet).

I want to do that :

https://gyazo.com/869c2f2f85b7054a43a7800bd32f44c4

And not take all the memory available. What is the better way ?

Answer (score 0):

I thin the best way is to use this library:
https://github.com/500px/500px-android-blur